# Tween camera to coordinates but preserve camera angle in three.js

Tags: three.js

I've seen a couple of questions on stack overflow about this but none resolve my issue.

For my first project in Three.Js I'm trying to create a tree and have the camera zoom in on specific nodes. I have the following code:

```
        var selectedObject = fourthParent;
        camera.target = selectedObject;
        var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(camera.position).to({
            x: selectedObject.position.x,
            y: selectedObject.position.y,
            z: 5
        },1000).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None).onUpdate(function () {
            camera.lookAt(camera.target);
        }).onComplete(function () {
            camera.lookAt(selectedObject.position);
        }).start();

        var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(camera.target).to({
            x: selectedObject.position.x,
            y: selectedObject.position.y,
            z: 0
        }).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None).onUpdate(function () {
        }).onComplete(function () {
            camera.lookAt(selectedObject.position);
        }).start();
```

This moves the camera correctly but right at the end of the animation it changes the camera angle. I'm not changing the angle in my code so I have no idea why it is changing. Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Joe

Here is the working code:

```
              updateControls = false;
              var selectedObject = fourthParent;
              camera.target = selectedObject;
              var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(camera.position).to({
                  x: selectedObject.position.x,
                  y: selectedObject.position.y,
                  z: 20
              },1000).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None).onComplete(function () {
                  controls.target0.set(selectedObject.position.x, selectedObject.position.y, selectedObject.position.z);
                  controls.position0.set(selectedObject.position.x, selectedObject.position.y, 20);
                  controls.reset();
                  updateControls = true;
              }).start();

              var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(camera.target).to({
                  x: selectedObject.position.x,
                  y: selectedObject.position.y,
                  z: 20
              }).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None).start();


    // Render loop
    var render = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        TWEEN.update();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        if (updateControls) {
            controls.update();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling `camera.lookAt()` you're changing the camera angle.
You should just remove every instance of that code.

Comment: Hi MrDoob, if I remove the calls to camera.lookAt it still exhibits the same behaviour, I've updated the code.

Comment: On the example you seem to be using controls, which you didn't mention on your question. If you remove the TrackballControls the camera angle shouldn't change.